# limit JavaScript append to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append text boxes when user clicks on button to body.But i want to append them only once while user is on that page.I have tried using counter to do that.But there is some minor issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
  var k=0;
    $('#show').click(function(){

      if(k==null){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('body').append('<br/>guve your name<input type="text" id="div'+ i +'" />');
        };
  };
   k=1;   
});

});</script>
```

in html

```
<button id="show">Hii</button>
```

Comment: Try using `$('#show').one("click", function() {});` ;)

Comment: Instead of `if(k==null){`, use `if(k<1){`

Comment: thanks eisbehr for  introducing to one.It worked

Comment: `0 != null`... Seems obvious no?

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** method to attach event handler, which only executes handler once for event type and element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show').one('click', function() {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('body').append('<br/>guve your name<input type="text" id="div' + i + '" />');
      };
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="show">Hii</button>
```

Comment: or change your if condition to `k==0`

Comment: Thnaks Pranav for answer

Comment: @DeepakGupta : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices here:

Check if the element exists (simplest).

As you're adding divs with IDs, they can be checked directly, which saves you needing to worry about a variable.

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    if ($("#div0").length == 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $('body').append('<br/>give your name<input type="text" id="div'+ i +'" />');
        };
    }
});
```

Use `one()` (least favourable option imo)

```
$('#show').one(function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

Remove (or disable) the button once it's been clicked

(the only sensible option for UX, that can be combined with one() if desired)

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#show').hide();
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) { ...
```